# Remote Images not loading in Firefox or Chrome (works in IE)

Tags: html, image, firefox

Here is an example, i boiled it down to as simple as i could
(random web image)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>
        Just a picture
        </TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
       <img crossorigin="Anonymous" src="http://www.fnordware.com/j2k/relax-orig.png" height="256" width="256">
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Works perfectly fine in IE, but does not show in chrome or firefox (I need it to work in firefox specifically).

Get Response is 200, but with no content (has content in IE response)

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-crossorigin) says: "If the server does not give credentials to the origin site (by not setting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: HTTP header), the image will be tainted and its usage restricted". No idea if that's what "restricted" mean anyway.

Answer (score 1):

only remove , crossorigin="Anonymous"

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
 <HTML>
   <HEAD>
    <TITLE>
    Just a picture
    </TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
   <img src="http://www.fnordware.com/j2k/relax-orig.png" height="256" width="256">
</BODY>
```

image sample in Firefox
[image]

Comment: This is a simple example to explain the problem. I need the cross origin element because ill actually be using the image in a webgl canvas which requires it. This SHOULD work, regardless of the flag